# convertDatetime dateStyle problems with firefox 'pt_PT'

Tags: java, jsf

I'm localising out current site and therefore aplying the JSF convertDatetime tag to all dates.

I have set the dateStyle to 'short'

For Internet Explorer with locale of pt_PT dates will show as '13-01-2012'.
While for Chrome with locale of pt_PT they show as '13-01-2012'.
Both these are fine.

A problem occurs with firefox; it does'nt seem to have a 'pt_PT' option!
So I select the 'pt' option instead.

A problem occurs in that the facescontect cannot find this locale:

```
setLocale(getFacesContext().getViewRoot().getLocale());
```

I know this as the above code return a locale of 'en_US', the next locale in the browser list.

Is this a known issue with firefox?

My faces-config is as follows:

```
<application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en_GB</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_IE</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_AU</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_NZ</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en_GB</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_BE</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_CA</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_FR</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_LU</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_MC</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr_CH</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>pt_PT</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>pt_BR</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <view-handler>org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler</view-handler>
        <message-bundle>com.resource.conversionmessages</message-bundle>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
```

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your Options->Content->Languages settings from Firefox?

Comment: Actually found the solution Viruzzo! Spent 30 minutes on it and the momment I posted this question I stumbled across the solution :) See my answer below.

Comment: Why don't you just use `pt` for Portugal and `pt_BR` for Brazil? You'd still need a country independent bundle for each supported language since what if I set my language to `en` or `fr` only?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Thomas, I'm about a minute ahead of you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added the following line to my supported locales in faces-config:

```
<supported-locale>pt</supported-locale>
```